# Source of SQL Server 2000 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

In a SQL Server 2000 database, I have a table that is being populated every day with refreshed data and an import date, but the DBA cannot locate the source of the table data. Is there a command to identify the source Ip address of the table's data or something similar?

Comment: One approach could be to restrict access to the table and see what breaks that day.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could enable [SQL Server 2000 Auditing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277388.aspx).

This is done by enabling `C2 Audit Mode` as follows:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'c2 audit mode', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

And then restart your database server. I will give some relevant quotes from the TN link:

> After you enable C2 auditing for the default database or for an instance, the database server will log all activity to the data directory that you specified during the installation process. (SQL Server doesn't let you log auditable events to an alternative location.) This directory holds the databases that SQL Server initially created. This directory is also the default location for all new databases and their transaction log files.
>
> SQL Server writes all auditable activity to a file with the format audittrace_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.trc, where YYYYMMDDHHMMSS is the log's creation time by year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.
>
> You can use SQL Server Profiler to view the log files that SQL Server creates. [...] You can't open the log file to which SQL Server is logging activity. If you need to access data in the current audit log, you'll need to wait until it fills up and the system creates a new log file, or simply stop and restart SQL Server.
>
> [...]Of particular interest are the EventClass column, which identifies the recorded auditable event; the TextData column, which contains the command (typically a stored procedure or SQL statement) that was executed in the database; the NTUserName and NTDomainName columns, which identify the user who ran the command; the ObjectName and DatabaseName columns, which identify the table, view, or stored procedure that was manipulated or invoked; and the StartTime column, which records when the command was issued. Of secondary interest might be the RoleName, TargetUserName, TargetLoginName, and DBUserName columns. Not all columns are populated for each event. [...].